# What are the requirements for crowns?

Tags: hot-shots-golf-wi

I recently got a crown for the first time on a level, now I'm wondering if there is a way for me to see in game what requirement is for each level.  If not, what exactly are the requirements to getting a crown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a list from [ps3trophies](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/hot-shots-golf-world-invitational/146720-list-crown-requirements.html):

> Hey guys, here is a list of the crown requirments for Hot shots golf hope this help some of you work on this long plat.
>   1-1: win with 2000 points or more
>   1-2: use a rising shot*
>   1-3: Hit GIR in 1 Stroke on a Par 4 and Win
>   1-4: win with par on frequency 100%
>   1-5: win with over 3 bogeys
>   1-vs: win with an eagle
>   2-1: just impact frequency 50% or more
>   2-2: fairway keep 100%
>   2-3: add a spin on all your shots
>   2-4: win with 2000 points or more
>   2-5: don't use a spin shot
>   2-vs: win within the first 3 holes
>   3-1: win with 10m or more putt/par or better
>   3-2: use a pin shot*
>   3-3: win with 3 birdies in a row
>   3-4: don't land in any roughs
>   3-5: win with 3 birdies in a row
>   3-vs: all holes must be done within 1 putt
>   4-1: total score must be -3 or less
>   4-2: fairway keep must be 80% or more
>   4-3: par on frequency 100%
>   4-4: total score must be -4 or less
>   4-5: win with no OB/WB
>   4-vs: win with consecutive birdies
>   5-1: 1m better pin (par on or better)
>   5-2: don't use spin shots
>   5-3: par on frequency 100%
>   5-4: get 1500 points or more
>   5-5: get a chip in birdie or better
>   5-vs: no bogeys
>   6-1: 2m better pin (par on or better)
>   6-2: no OB/WB
>   6-3: no bankers
>   6-4: 3m better pin (par on or better)
>   6-5: get a birdie or better on the last hole
>   6-vs: don't use power mode

I've also figured out what the two shot types are:

Rising shot - You must put tremendous top spin onto your shot and your ball has to traverse up the pin.

Pin shot - Your shot has to hit the pin.

Not sure what OB/WB and DP/WB means though.

Comment: OB is usually 'out of bounds' in golf; never heard of WB but it might be getting in a bunker?